# -bash: 400:: command not found when open terminal

Tags: bash

I have tried to install *git-completion.bash* on *OSX* using Terminal.
Process needed to edit `~/.bash_profile` as such.
I used `vi ~/.bash_profile`. After this changes, when I open my *Terminal* I see `-bash: 400:: command not found` and I'm not able to edit again!.
In addition to that, I have *two* different *bash_profile* in my home directory, `.bash_profile.swo`  & `.bash_profile.swp`.
Can anyone please advise how can I resolve this issue?

Here is my `.bash_profile`:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.4     # The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave   
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"    
export PATH      # Setting PATH for Python 3.5      # The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave    
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"    
export PATH      # added by Anaconda3 4.0.0 installer    
export PATH="//anaconda/bin:$PATH"      # added by Anaconda3 4.0.0 installer    
export PATH="/anaconda/anaconda/bin:$PATH"      # Setting PATH for Python 3.5      # The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave        
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"    
export PATH      # added by Anaconda3 4.1.1 installer    
export PATH="//anaconda/bin:$PATH"      # Setting PATH for Python 3.5      # The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave    
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"    
export PATH      # Setting PATH for Python 3.5      # The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave    
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"   
export PATH      # Setting PATH for Python 3.5     # The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave   
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"   
export PATH   
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8   
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8     # added by Anaconda3 4.1.1 installer    
export PATH="/Users/shahramkarimi/anaconda/bin:$PATH"      # Setting PATH for Python 3.6      # The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave    
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"    
export PATH      # added by Anaconda3 4.3.1 installer    
export PATH="/Users/shahramkarimi/anaconda/bin:$PATH"      # added by Anaconda3 4.3.1 installer    
export PATH="/Users/shahramkarimi/anaconda/bin:$PATH"        # added by Anaconda3 4.4.0 installer    
export PATH="/Users/shahramkarimi/anaconda/bin:$PATH"      # added by Anaconda3 5.0.1 installer    
export PATH="/Users/shahramkarimi/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"      # Show always fullpath on terminal      #export PS1='\u@\H:\w$ '    
export PS1='\u \w$ '    
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then     
 . ~/.git-completion.bash   
fi
```

Comment: post the contents of .bash_profile

Comment: @ilkkachu why did you downgrade the question?

Comment: @Shahram ilkkachu *edited* the question to improve the formatting and make it easier to read. There is no way of knowing who downvoted and no reason to assume it was ilkkachu. Now, I didn't downvote, but the reason somebody did is because you tell us you made some changes, but don't actually show us the file or what changes you made. So how can we help you fix something if you don't tell us what you did? Please [edit] your question and show us the contents of your `~/.bash_profile` file (ignore `.bash_profile.swo` and `.bash_profile.swp`).

Comment: @terdon and ilkkachu  sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: No problem, we know the system can be confusing here :) So. Your `~./.bash_profile` seems OK. The problem will therefore be in one of the other files read by the shell.  What is the output of `grep -H 400 ~/.git-completion.bash ~/.profile ~/etc/profile`?

Comment: @terdon thank you very much for the advice.  The output is `/Users/shahramkarimi/.git-completion.bash:400: Invalid request`  and for two others `No such file or directory`

Comment: @Shahram great. So the problem is a syntax error in `.git-completion.bash`. If the only issue is that line, then remove the line and try again (remember to [accept](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) dr01's answer below). If not, we will need to see the `~/.git-completion.bash` to understand. Is this a file you tried to download from somewhere? Could it be that the download failed?

Comment: @terdon you were right, thank you very much . the error was `.git-completion.bash` file. I have deleted and error disappeared.  I have used the `.git-completion.bash` via this GitHub link `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash  -o ~/.git-completion.bash`. I'm not gonna use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.bash_profile.swo` and `.bash_profile.swp` files are simply temporary files created by Vim.  The `.swp` file was created when you opened `.bash_profile` in the editor, and the `.swo` was created when you edited `.bash_profile` and `.bash_profile.swp` already existed.

For the error, check your `~/.git-completion.bash`, `~/.profile`, and `~/etc/profile` files. Probably there's a line

```
400::
```

somewhere, and Bash interprets this as a command. You can check this via this command:

```
grep -H 400 ~/.git-completion.bash ~/.profile ~/etc/profile
```

(Post edited, thanks to @terdon for the suggestions.)

Comment: `~/.git-completion.bash` was the error. I just deleted the file and have no error on shell. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sudo -i
-bash: 400:: command not found

# ls -rt /etc/bash_completion.d/|tail -1
kubectl

# cat /etc/bash_completion.d/kubectl
400: Invalid request
```

A broken bash completion file (`kubectl` in this case) is causing the error.

Remove the broken file:

```
# rm /etc/bash_completion.d/kubectl
# exit
$ sudo -i
```

Enjoy.